# Change color of UISwitch in "off" state

Tags: iphone, ios, uiswitch

I've learned that we can change the UISwitch button appearance in its "on" state,
but is it also possible to change the color of the UISwitch in the "off" state?

Comment: have you used tintColor property to change colour?

Answer (score 192):

My solution with #swift2:

```
let onColor  = _your_on_state_color
let offColor = _your_off_state_color

let mSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRect.zero)
mSwitch.on = true

/*For on state*/
mSwitch.onTintColor = onColor

/*For off state*/
mSwitch.tintColor = offColor
mSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = mSwitch.frame.height / 2.0
mSwitch.backgroundColor = offColor
mSwitch.clipsToBounds = true
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey, @longpham , I would just make a little change on the radius code. In case the height ever changes I would use: mSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = mSwitch.frame.height/2 (I'm just paranoid).

Comment: @Felipe Gringo No problem. Depend on your UI. Standard `UISwitch` is 31pt.

Answer (score 149):

Try using this

```
yourSwitch.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
youSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0;
```

All thanks to @Barry Wyckoff.

Comment: THIS is correct answer:) setTint changes the "outline" colour as well which visually "hides" the background on white background.

Comment: Be aware that the background is in rectangular shape.

Comment: My switch is resized with `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.80, 0.80)`. And this is not working with scaled view. Because view's layer is not resized. How can i make this work?

Comment: @aykutt for scaled view you can use yourSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = yourSwitch.frame.height / 2 / scaleFactor

Answer (score 49):

You can use the `tintColor` property on the switch.

```
switch.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // the "off" color
switch.onTintColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // the "on" color
```

Note this requires iOS 5+

Comment: Setting tintColor in iOS7 removes "outline" for me (tint white against white background).

Answer (score 31):

Swift IBDesignable

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable

class UISwitchCustom: UISwitch {
    @IBInspectable var OffTint: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            self.tintColor = OffTint
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 16
            self.backgroundColor = OffTint
        }
    }
}
```

set class in Identity inspector

[image]

change color from Attributes inspector

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: It is not giving proper out put in swift 3

Comment: @KetanP can you explain issue in more detail?

Comment: running Xcode 11.2.1, works when running the app, but it does not show the color in IB.... anyway, it works when deployed to device.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a pretty good trick: you can just reach right into the UISwitch's subview that draws its "off" background, and change its background color. This works a lot better in iOS 13 than it does in iOS 12:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    self.sw.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = .green
} else if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    self.sw.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = .green
}
```

Comment: Probably not crash during subscription in future iOS better to use subviews.first?. instead of subviews[0].

Comment: @IgorPalaguta Yes, good idea. I'll make that change.

Comment: @ Igor Palaguta, here we have 2 subviews, can you please post your complete code.

Comment: Minor issue to be aware of with this technique; for some reason, iOS likes to erase this color back to the default once the app comes back from the background.

Answer (score 13):

[image]
[image]
Working 100% IOS 13.0 and Swift 5.0 switch both state color set same #ios13 #swift #swift5

```
@IBOutlet weak var switchProfile: UISwitch!{
    didSet{
        switchProfile.onTintColor = .red
        switchProfile.tintColor = .red
        switchProfile.subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work with colors that adapt to the dark mode.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me. To use it on dark mode, don't use ".red", use ".systemRed"

Answer (score 8):

> The Best way to manage background color & size of UISwitch

For now it's Swift 2.3 code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class UICustomSwitch : UISwitch {

    @IBInspectable var OnColor : UIColor! = UIColor.blueColor()
    @IBInspectable var OffColor : UIColor! = UIColor.grayColor()
    @IBInspectable var Scale : CGFloat! = 1.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setUpCustomUserInterface()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setUpCustomUserInterface()
    }


    func setUpCustomUserInterface() {

        //clip the background color
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        //Scale down to make it smaller in look
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.Scale, self.Scale);

        //add target to get user interation to update user-interface accordingly
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UICustomSwitch.updateUI), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        //set onTintColor : is necessary to make it colored
        self.onTintColor = self.OnColor

        //setup to initial state
        self.updateUI()
    }

    //to track programatic update
    override func setOn(on: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setOn(on, animated: true)
        updateUI()
    }

    //Update user-interface according to on/off state
    func updateUI() {
        if self.on == true {
            self.backgroundColor = self.OnColor
        }
        else {
            self.backgroundColor = self.OffColor
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5:

```
import UIKit

extension UISwitch {    

    func set(offTint color: UIColor ) {
        let minSide = min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width)
        layer.cornerRadius = minSide / 2
        backgroundColor = color
        tintColor = color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Should you need other switches around your app, it might be also a good idea implementing @LongPham's code inside a custom class.
As others have pointed out, for the "off" state you'll need to change the background colour as well, since the default is transparent.

```
class MySwitch: UISwitch {

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Setting "on" state colour
    self.onTintColor        = UIColor.green

    // Setting "off" state colour
    self.tintColor          = UIColor.red
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
    self.backgroundColor    = UIColor.red
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4** easiest and fastest way to get it in 3 steps:

```
// background color is the color of the background of the switch
switchControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.9)

// tint color is the color of the border when the switch is off, use
// clear if you want it the same as the background, or different otherwise
switchControl.tintColor = UIColor.clear

// and make sure that the background color will stay in border of the switch
switchControl.layer.cornerRadius = switchControl.bounds.height / 2
```

If you manually change the size of the switch (e.g., by using autolayout), you will have to update the `switch.layer.cornerRadius` too, e.g., by overriding `layoutSubviews` and after calling super updating the corner radius:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    switchControl.layer.cornerRadius = switchControl.bounds.height / 2
}
```

Comment: what is integrationSwitch? and also, doesnt seem to work in iOS 11. Changing the background color changes a larger looking view around the switch

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile sorry, it should be `switchControl`

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile it's supposed to change the background color, not the bullet itself.. in iOS look and feel that's always the default color..

Answer (score 4):

**2020 As of Xcode 11.3.1 & Swift 5**

Here's the simplest way I've found of doing setting the UISwitch off-state colour with *one line of code*. Writing this here since this page is what came up first when I was looking and the other answers didn't help.

This is if I wanted to set the off state to be red, and can be added to the viewDidLoad() function:

```
yourSwitchName.subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Note - what this is actually doing is setting the background colour of the switch. **This may influence the colour of the switch in the on-state too** (though for me this wasn't a problem since I wanted the on and off state to be the same colour).

**A solution for this:**

Simply tie in the colours with an 'if else' statement inside your IBAction. If the switch is off, colour the background red. If the switch is on, leave the background *clear* so your chosen 'on' colour will display properly.

This goes **inside** the switch IBAction.

```
  if yourSwitch.isOn == false {
           yourSwitch.subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    } else {
        yourSwitch.subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
```

I found some behaviour where, upon the app resuming from background, the switch background would return to clear. To remedy this problem I simply added in the following code to set the colour every time the app comes to the foreground:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)),
      name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
      object: nil)
}

@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ notification: NSNotification) {
   yourSwitch.subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   yourSwitch.subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Seems simpler than the other answers. Hope that helps!

Comment: Beautiful and simple answer, thank you very much,  +1

Comment: This method shows strange area on iOS 12.

Answer (score 3):

The UISwitch `offTintColor` is transparent, so whatever is behind the switch shows through. Therefore, instead of masking the background color, it suffices to draw a switch-shaped image *behind* the switch (this implementation assumes that the switch is positioned by autolayout):

```
func putColor(_ color: UIColor, behindSwitch sw: UISwitch) {
    guard sw.superview != nil else {return}
    let onswitch = UISwitch()
    onswitch.isOn = true
    let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds:sw.bounds)
    let im = r.image { ctx in
        onswitch.layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
        }.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let iv = UIImageView(image:im)
    iv.tintColor = color
    sw.superview!.insertSubview(iv, belowSubview: sw)
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        iv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sw.topAnchor),
        iv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sw.bottomAnchor),
        iv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sw.leadingAnchor),
        iv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sw.trailingAnchor),
    ])
}
```

[But see now my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142728/341994).]

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4+:

`off` state:

```
switch.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

`on` state:

```
switch.onTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 13+, setting `tintColor` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

objective c category to use on any UISwitch in project using code or storyboard:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UISwitch (SAHelper)
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *offTint;
@end
```

implementation

```
#import "UISwitch+SAHelper.h"

@implementation UISwitch (SAHelper)
@dynamic offTint;
- (void)setOffTint:(UIColor *)offTint {
    self.tintColor = offTint;   //comment this line to hide border in off state
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
    self.backgroundColor = offTint;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

More safe way in **Swift 3** without magical 16pt values:

```
class ColoredBackgroundSwitch: UISwitch {

  var offTintColor: UIColor {
    get {
      return backgroundColor ?? UIColor.clear
    }
    set {
      backgroundColor = newValue
    }
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let minSide = min(frame.size.height, frame.size.width)
    layer.cornerRadius = ceil(minSide / 2)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**XCode 11, Swift 5**

I don't prefer using subViews, cause you never know when apple gonna change the hierarchy.

so I use mask view instead.

it works with iOS 12, iOS 13

```
    private lazy var settingSwitch: UISwitch = {
        let swt: UISwitch = UISwitch()
        // set border color when isOn is false
        swt.tintColor = .cloudyBlueTwo
        // set border color when isOn is true
        swt.onTintColor = .greenishTeal

        // set background color when isOn is false
        swt.backgroundColor = .cloudyBlueTwo

        // create a mask view to clip background over the size you expected.
        let maskView = UIView(frame: swt.frame)
        maskView.backgroundColor = .red
        maskView.layer.cornerRadius = swt.frame.height / 2
        maskView.clipsToBounds = true
        swt.mask = maskView

        // set the scale to your expectation, here is around height: 34, width: 21.
        let scale: CGFloat = 2 / 3
        swt.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        swt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchOnChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return swt
    }()

    @objc
    func switchOnChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            // set background color when isOn is true
            sender.backgroundColor = .greenishTeal
        } else {
            // set background color when isOn is false
            sender.backgroundColor = .cloudyBlueTwo
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested on IOS 14, set background as off color and onTintColor as On and works:

```
uiSwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.blue
uiSwitch.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on iOS 16. backgroundColor colors the whole switch box and omits rounded corners. As others suggested below you need to add a .layer.cornerRadius

Comment: I updated my App for IOS 16 and still working ok. no need to add nothing more on my app.

Answer (score 0):

**XCode 11, Swift 4.2**

Starting with [Matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580695/1531971) I added it to a custom, IBDesignable control. There is a timing issue in that `didMoveToSuperview()` is called before the `offTintColor` is set that needed to be handled.

```
@IBDesignable public class UISwitchCustom: UISwitch {

    var switchMask: UIImageView?
    private var observers = [NSKeyValueObservation]()

    @IBInspectable dynamic var offTintColor : UIColor! = UIColor.gray {
        didSet {
             switchMask?.tintColor = offTintColor
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeObservers()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeObservers()
    }

    private func initializeObservers() {
        observers.append(observe(\.isHidden, options: [.initial]) {(model, change) in
            self.switchMask?.isHidden = self.isHidden
        })
    }

    override public func didMoveToSuperview() {
        addOffColorMask(offTintColor)
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
    }

   private func addOffColorMask(_ color: UIColor) {
        guard self.superview != nil else {return}
        let onswitch = UISwitch()
        onswitch.isOn = true
        let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds:self.bounds)
        let im = r.image { ctx in
            onswitch.layer.render(in: ctx.cgContext)
            }.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let iv = UIImageView(image:im)
        iv.tintColor = color
        self.superview!.insertSubview(iv, belowSubview: self)
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            iv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            iv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            iv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            iv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            ])
        switchMask = iv
        switchMask?.isHidden = self.isHidden
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

all I finally used transform and layer.cornerRadius too.
But I have added translation to it to be center.

```
    private func setSwitchSize() {
    let iosSwitchSize = switchBlockAction.bounds.size
    let requiredSwitchSize = ...
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(a: requiredSwitchSize.width / iosSwitchSize.width, b: 0,
                                      c: 0, d:  requiredSwitchSize.height / iosSwitchSize.height,
                                      tx: (requiredSwitchSize.width - iosSwitchSize.width) / 2.0,
                                      ty: (requiredSwitchSize.height - iosSwitchSize.height) / 2.0)

    switchBlockAction.layer.cornerRadius = iosSwitchSize.height / 2.0
    switchBlockAction.transform = transform
}
```

And I did use backgroundColor and tintColor in designer.
Hope it helps.