# How to change UISwitch default color for OFF state?

Tags: ios, uiswitch, tintcolor

I want to change the color of  onTintColor in the UISwitch for the off State. The switch is in tableview and switch is made programmatically.

```
    [settingsSwitch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [settingsSwitch setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [settingsSwitch setThumbTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [settingsSwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:138/256.0  green:9/256.0 blue:18/256.0 alpha:1]];
```

[image]

This is the result i get when i set the background color white.

[image]

And without background i get red color which is the color of my cell.

[image]

and this is the result i want, when switch is on the onTintColor should b dark red, and in off state it should be white.

i tried setting the image on switch with this line of code

```
[settingsSwitch setOnImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on.png"]];
[settingsSwitch setOffImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off.png"]];
```

But its not changing the images.
i want to change the color of switch in off state.
Hope i have explained my question clearly.thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Not sure if that is a good idea. It looks like the on switch is off. And the off switch looks like it's on. (Because it has a bright, white, active looking color).

Comment: I agree but that's the requirement of the client.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper, Client is always right :)

Comment: Is it possible to give border to the switch

Answer (score 6):

You can use following CODE to fulfill requirement.

**Your ViewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    settingsSwitch.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0; // you must import QuartzCore to do this


    if (settingsSwitch.on) {
        NSLog(@"If body ");
        [settingsSwitch setThumbTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [settingsSwitch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [settingsSwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Else body ");

        [settingsSwitch setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [settingsSwitch setThumbTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [settingsSwitch setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:138/256.0 green:9/256.0 blue:18/256.0 alpha:1]];
    }
}
```

**Method where status change IBAction is called.**

```
- (IBAction)switchStatusChange:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    if (sender.on) {
        NSLog(@"If body ");
        [sender setThumbTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [sender setOnTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Else body ");

        [sender setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [sender setThumbTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:138/256.0 green:9/256.0 blue:18/256.0 alpha:1]];
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually works, but it screws with the thumb animation (to left or right). Any workarounds?

Comment: how could we make it smooth

Comment: it works but not giving smooth animation. any way to solve this? Veer bro.

Comment: @MRizwan33 try wrapping in dispatch queue main async

Comment: @DaniSpringer (Y)

Comment: @NabeelAhmed what?

Comment: @DaniSpringer " try wrapping in dispatch queue main async"

Its works for me thumbs up fro you :)

Comment: @NabeelAhmed ok awesome! Yeah always update UI on main thread. User shouldn't have to deal with unresponsive interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can use you first approach + add border radius to remove unwanted corners:

```
slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
slider.layer.cornerRadius = 18.0;
```

Originally from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22830039/1994445) answer.

Comment: cornerRadius affect in the border corner, its a poor solution

Answer (score 1):

corner in UISwitch cut the view, and isn't see rounded, the best answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38564168/6609238