# Is there any way to not gray/fade out the UISwitch when it's disabled in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

Is there any way to not gray/fade out the UISwitch when it's disabled in Swift? Just turn off user interaction and keep the 'normal' on/off look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348869/change-color-of-uiswitch-in-off-state

Answer (score 1):

Just `SWITCH.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`