# UISwitch ".onTintColor" and ".tintColor" not working

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I'm attempt to change the tint color of all my toggles within my app to blue. I tried using both ***UISwitch.appearance().tintColor*** and ***UISwitch.appearance().onTintColor*** with no help.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Studently: App {
        
    init() {
        UISwitch.appearance().tintColor = .systemBlue
        UISwitch.appearance().onTintColor = .systemBlue
    }
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabBar()
        }
    }
}
```

[Image: .onTintColor and .tintColor does nothing in another view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERIKQ.png)

The weird thing is, if the state property wrapper is true, the color will be applied. But once toggled to off then on, it returns back to standard green.

[Image: Color only applied if the state property wrapped is set to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKlqZ.png)

I thought maybe this was just a human error on my end. So I tested this out more using ***UISwitch.appearance.thumbTintColor*** which applies to a toggle within another view.

```
@main

struct Studently: App {
        
    init() {
        UISwitch.appearance().tintColor = .systemBlue
        UISwitch.appearance().onTintColor = .systemBlue
        UISwitch.appearance().thumbTintColor = .red
    }
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabBar()
        }
    }
}
```

[Image: .thumbTintColor changes the circle to red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG9nh.png)

****.thumbTintColor**** is just for example that it can be applied, but neither ****.tintColor**** or ****.onTintColor**** are applied.

Of course, using ****.tint**** works when applied to a single toggle, but I want this to apply to all Toggles without using ****.tint**** on each one.

How can I achieve or fix this?

Comment: Are you using SwitchUI? Why aren't you using a Toggle component? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toggle Alternatively if you are using UIKit UISwift - try to assign the `onTintColor` and `thumbTintColor` on the instance - not through appearance - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348869/change-color-of-uiswitch-in-off-state

Comment: @CloudBalancing I am using SwiftUI. I was just unaware if UISwitch could work within SwiftUI as well

Comment: As such, use the Toggle component of SwiftUI - why mixing UIKit components is that mandatory?

Comment: @CloudBalancing no no no, not mandatory. I just thought UISwitch belonged with Toggle in UIKIt